# How and where can I start learning about electronics?

Tags: basic

I really want to know how electronic devices work.

So as someone ***who actually knows nothing about basics, how can I start learning it? What sources should I use? Is it really needed to be studying at university?***

We haven't been taught anything about electronics at school in my country and I haven't found any online courses or classes in my own language for beginners.

I have done such things before in school and home like creating a radio or alarm, etc. but no one ever told us how they actually work. They haven't ever told what is the essence of electronics, for example why should be that resistor be before that transistor, etc.

Comment: Today you can learn virtually anything online and for free at a university level quality. Start [here](https://www.edx.org/course/circuits-electronics-1-basic-circuit-mitx-6-002-1x-0)

Comment: When I was much younger than you (Internet did not exist yet), I went to the local library and read **everything** related to electronics. I got some parts from discarded radios etc. Experimented with some simple circuits. Today all this is so much easier with all the info on the Internet so read everything that interests you and take it from there. Instead of asking where to find this knowledge, **go and seek it yourself !**

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn electronics is to get a few parts and start tinkering, usually at age 12 or earlier.  You are starting late, but it's still possible.  Get some transistors, resistors, and capacitors and start building simple circuits.

Comment: Actually I have done such thing before in school like crafting a radio or .... but they did not taught us anyrhing about the real basic. l mean they didn't ever told us how a transistor works or how are electrical circuit made

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix stuff. *Like*, a lot of stuff. Be careful with mains-powered equipment, though.

Fixing a broken device has the advantage that you know exactly when your reasoning was right. Also, you are probably led along many false routes during the process, and once you found the cause, in hindsight, it appears all too easy. This makes you keep a modest attitude towards building your own circuits in the best possible way and you learn to question your designs.

You can never learn enough from fixing stuff. Here's an excerpt from [Jim Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Williams_%28analog_designer%29)' article "The Importance of Fixing", as published in the book ART & SCIENCE OF ANALOG CIRCUIT DESIGN:

[image]

Oh how I like the part about fooling yourself...